# How to disable the drag to the Action-bar for whole android app?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, draggable

I did the following in my onCreate method

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.hide();
```

but if I touch and drag the actionbar it is displayed? how can I disable the displaying of actionbar when touch and drag?

thank you